# Ignore null values while doing validation of input fields

Tags: java, validation, nullable

I have a class with the following elements:

```
public class Details {
    private String locale;
    private String url;
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Now from my client I receive a List. I want to perform some validation over these elements. However it is not necessary that all elements are presents (null is acceptable).

```
List<Details> detailsList;

Validate.notNull(detailsList);
for(Details details: detailsList) {
    if(details.getLocale() != null) {
        Validate.isTrue(StringUtils.isNotBlank(LocaleUtils.toLocale(details.getLocale()).getVariant()));
    }
    if(details.getUrl() != null) {
        Validate.isTrue(urlValidator.isValid(details.getUrl()));
    }
    //Similarly perform null checks and then do the validation.
}
```

Is there a better way for me to write this validation instead of writing null checks for each field?

Comment: Use JSR-303 validation?

Answer (score 0):

Just to take the `Locale` example from your code, what I understand is:

- A null value is acceptable
- But if it's not null, then it must be a valid `Locale` with a variant

This makes "nullness" part of your validation criteria, and therefore you can simply prepend a `== null || <valid>` expression. For example:

```
Validate.isTrue(details.getLocale() == null || StringUtils.isNotBlank(...));
```

With new Java 8 `Optional<>` class there are further choices of syntax to make clear what your intention is. The following code illustrates this. Choose your preference.

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.*;

public class OptionalTest {

  public static class TestObject1 {
    String locale;
    public TestObject1(String locale) {
      this.locale = locale;
    }
  }

  public static class TestObject2 {
    Optional<String> locale;
    public TestObject2(String locale) {
      this.locale = Optional.ofNullable(locale);
    }
  }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
     validate1(new TestObject1("en_GB_EURO"));
     validate1(new TestObject1(null));

     validate2(new TestObject2("en_GB_EURO"));
     validate2(new TestObject2(null));

     validate3(new TestObject2("en_GB_EURO"));
     validate3(new TestObject2(null));
   }

   private static void validate1(TestObject1 to) {
     Validate.isTrue(to.locale == null || StringUtils.isNotBlank(LocaleUtils.toLocale(to.locale).getVariant()));
   }

   private static void validate2(TestObject2 to) {
     Validate.isTrue(!to.locale.isPresent() || StringUtils.isNotBlank(LocaleUtils.toLocale(to.locale.get()).getVariant()));
   }

   private static void validate3(TestObject2 to) {
     to.locale.ifPresent(loc -> {
       Validate.isTrue(StringUtils.isNotBlank(LocaleUtils.toLocale(loc).getVariant()));
     });
   }
}
```